# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: словообразование, числительные

Если "один", то "одинарный", если "два", то "двойной", "три" - "тройной", а если "пять"? "Пятерной" или "пятеричный"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Одинарный, двойной, тройной*  - прилагательные, содержащие компонент значения (сему) 'состоящий из N-ного количества частей', где N - соответствует числу, содержащемуся в корне слова. В слове *одинарный* суффикс -арн-, в словах *двойной, тройной*  по два суффикса (-ой- и -н-), потому что образованы они от собирательных числительных *двое* и *трое* соотвественно. Следуя этой логике, прилагательные от числительных четыре, пять образуются таким же образом: четыре > четв**ер**о > четвер**н**ой, пять > пят**ер**о > пятер**н**ой. И *четверной*, и **пятерной** в словарях толкуются как '*состоящий из четырёх однородных или подобных частей, предметов; имеющий четыре однородные или подобные части*' и '*состоящий из пяти однородных или подобных частей, предметов; имеющий пять однородных или подобных части*', то есть ровно с той же семой, что и *двойной, тройной*.

Что касается слова **пятеричный**, то в современном русском языке оно считается устаревшим, хотя в пору своего широкого бытования имело значение 'в пять раз больший; *состоящий из пяти каких-н. единиц*'. К тому же оно созвучно прилагательным *двоичный, троИчный*, которые относятся к системам счета. Поэтому если вы хотите сказать, что что-то состоит из пяти частей, компонентов, без опаски можете употреблять слово **пятерной**.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как в словаре:
ПЯТЕРНОЙ, -ая, -ое. Разг.
1.
Состоящий из пяти однородных или подобных частей, предметов; имеющий пять однородных или подобных частей. П-ое трюмо. П-ые листочки.
2.
В пять раз больший, увеличенный в пять раз. П-ая плата.
Пятеричный в аналогичном значении  - устаревшее. Возможно, есть такой термин? Как двоичный, десятеричный.

Answer (score 1):

Словам "пятерной" и "шестерной" я бы предпочла сложно образованные слова типа пятислойный, шестиуровневый, семичастный ... Неполнота парадигм - обычное явление в языке. Так, у единицы - четыре формы: один, одна, одно, одни; у двойки - две: два и две; а у всех остальных чисел и вовсе по одной: три, четыре, пять и т.д.

Comment: Слово пятерной имеется в словарях, причем без каких-либо помет, ограничивающих употребление. Без контекста трудно говорить о предпочтительности использования того или иного слова.

Comment: Мой комментарий относится не к вопросу  get_backers, а к ответу  olsa, который написал:"... если хотите сказать, что что-то состоит из пяти частей, компонентов, без опаски можете употреблять слово "пятерной". Кстати, системный редактор подчёркивает слово "пятерной", как отсутствующее в его словаре, что указывает на нечастотность данного слова, а, следовательно, и на вполне возможную специфичность  употребления. Я полностью с Вами согласна, что "без контекста трудно говорить о предпочтительности использования того или иного слова". А вот на данные словарей безоглядно не стала бы полагаться.

Comment: "Мой комментарий относится не к вопросу get_backers, а к ответу olsa" Сделать коммаентарием? Или все-таки это был общий ответ?

Comment: Думаю, что нужно оставить всё как есть, чтобы окончательно не запутаться. В будущем постараюсь быть внимательнее.